# If hover: re-call function after animation has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scroll

I have a shelf of content which is scrollable. When you hover over the left or right buttons, the shelf slides as such. This all works perfectly.

When you click the left or right buttons the shelf jumps the width of the shelf. Also working perfectly.

What I would like to do is for the shelf to continue scrolling after the jump, where as at the moment it stops all together until you re-hover your mouse. I presume this is just re-calling the function after the jump is complete, so i have added an `if (hover)` after `.promise().done()`, however I'm not sure of the rest.

Please advise.

Thanks.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mNrCD/)

```
function shelfScroll(el, modifier){
        var sl = el.scrollLeft();
        el.animate({scrollLeft: sl + (modifier * 100)}, 450, 'linear', function(){ 
                if(hover){
                        shelfScroll(el, modifier);
                }
        });
}
var hover = false;
$('.scroll-arrow').each(function() {
        var modifier = ($(this).hasClass('scroll-arrow-right')) ? 1 : -1;
        var sib = ('.shelf-slide');
        var shelf_width = $(this).siblings(sib).width();
        $(this).hover(function() {
                hover = true;
                $(this).siblings(sib).stop();
                shelfScroll($(this).siblings(sib), modifier);
        }, function() {
                hover = false;
                $(this).siblings(sib).stop();
        }).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).siblings(sib).stop();
                $(this).siblings(sib).animate({scrollLeft: $(this).siblings(sib).scrollLeft() + (modifier * shelf_width)}, 500);
                $(this).siblings(sib).promise().done(function() {
                        if (hover){

                        } else{

                        }
                });

        });
});
```

Comment: this might help http://forum.jquery.com/topic/stop-and-reactivate-hover-event

Comment: you can use the callback of animate like this [http://jsfiddle.net/mNrCD/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/mNrCD/1/)

Comment: I love the simplicity of this but could you please explain exactly how it works? I understand you're calling back the function, but how does the modifier bit come into it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the possible [jQuery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) I found `mouseover()` can handle or *trigger* the event. Put `$('.scroll-arrow').mouseover();` in your `if (hover)` check and it should work.

**EDIT** I tried it in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7VTT/), and noticed you'll have to keep track of which arrow is/was hovered, but this should get you on track